# Copy the File and Change Name at Same Time by DOS

Tags: windows, for-loop, batch-file, cmd, rename

Files located like this

```
folderA/aaa.html
folderA/bbb.html
```

I want to copy them to `folderB` but different location, like

```
folderB/aaa/index.html
folderB/bbb/index.html
```

I tried

```
for /R "C:\...\folderA\" %%f in (*.html) do copy /y "%%f" "%%~nf/index.html"
```

Not working because I have no place to put `folderB`

Please help

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
@echo off &setlocal
for %%i in (folderA\*.html) do (
    for /f "delims=" %%j in ("%%~dpi.") do (
        md "%%~dpjfolderB\%%~ni"
        copy "%%~fi" "%%~dpjfolderB\%%~ni\index.html"
    )
)
```

Comment: Very impressive. How about `folderA/aaa/ccc.html`, I would like it become `folderB/aaa/ccc/index.html` current solution cannot process subdirectories. Btw,what is this `%%~dpi` stuff, is there any reference

Comment: You get help on the command line, for help type `help for`  :)